# Add Enterprise Library 6 without powershell?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012

I've been trying to install Enterprise Library 6, and it's been a pain. I tried following [Enterprise Library 6: Installation and VS2012 Configuration](https://randylevy.wordpress.com/2013/04/30/enterprise-library-6-installation-and-vs2012-configuration/), but I'm having issues with the powershell command. I also tried opening `install-packages.ps1` and pasting in powershell, and I keep continue errors. I'm not sure if it's my machine and the restrictions it has, but I don't want to go through this installation process just for one call to a stored procedure.

I rarely use powershell, and I don't want to start learning it today. Is there a way to just download the dlls needed and add them as reference to my project?

I had already added `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data` as reference, and the project builds well, but when it runs, I get an error with one of the methods. It seems that there are other dlls I need to add (`Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common`), among others.

I just want to download these dlls and add them as reference. I don't want to go through any installation process.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Would be useful if you shared the error, so we could understand the fully issue.

Comment: There isn't an issue. I simply want to know if I can use Enterprise Library 6 without using nuget or powershell. And it seems that  I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded [Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ConfigConsoleV6.vsix](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/B/4/BB4234FA-F238-4BDE-8A63-FFB6B2D81761/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ConfigConsoleV6.vsix). Then I opened in winrar, copy/pasted `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll` to my bin folder, and added as reference to my project.

Then I downloaded `enterpriselibrary.data.6.0.1304.nupkg` from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/EnterpriseLibrary.Data/6.0.1304) and opened it with winrar. Then I copy/pasted `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll` to my bin folder, and added as reference to my project.

---